# Rails select and collection select helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is a preference question I'm sure.

*EDIT*
Recently, I've noticed this code in a few public examples of VIEW code:

```
f.collection_select :my_method, AddressTypes.all, :name, :name
```

or

```
f.select :my_method, ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3']
```

instead of ...

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @address_types = AddressTypes.all
  end

end
```

Obviously, in the view:

```
f.collection_select :my_method, @address_types, :name, :name
```

Is this just personal preference?  Or is there another reason, of which I am not aware?

Comment: it shouldn't be "f.collection_select :my_method, AddressTypes.all, :id, :name" ?

Comment: collection_select and select was used inside the view not in the controller no ? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

Comment: @awea, ok, I'll try to make this more clear?

Comment: @andredurao, you're missing the point, and no

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I think it comes down to personal preference, even the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) use `Model.all` right in the view rather than pulling that back to the controller.

My preference is that as soon as I'm doing anything more than `Model.all`, maybe a `Model.where(:foo => "bar")` or something, the query should be abstracted back to the controller, or preferably the model. The view shouldn't be responsible for your model/data's logic, it should just be concerned with presenting it.